# Getting the Django admin media

Tags: javascript, django, django-admin

The Django Admin module includes several of its own JavaScript files on several pages. I would like to include these media files for a custom view. How can I do this?

I've looked through the admin templates but I'm not sure what the best way to do this is.

**Update**: Or, I could just go to a page and copy/paste the scripts. Although it feels like there's a better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

In settings.py you need enable context processors -  TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

```
("django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
"django.core.context_processors.debug",
"django.core.context_processors.i18n",
"django.core.context_processors.media",
"django.core.context_processors.static",
"django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages")
```

can read more here  http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext
If you are using render_to_response function, you can return something like this

```
return render_to_response('template.html', {}, RequestContext(request))
```

after this you can use media option in your templates like {{ ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX }}js/name_of_file.js

Comment: It's good to add that those are enabled by default even without it specified in settings.

Comment: So I have to specify all the .js files manually, instead of grabbing them all from someplace? Also, putting `{{ ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX }} ` in my template doesn't cause anything to be printed.